# Places Autocomplete always returns Chicago resultas even If lat long is set to other place

Tags: google-maps, location, google-places-api

I'm using Google places API to check the places nearby and let the user pick one. Everything works fine but I'm having location issues, If I send the longitude and latitude to the api call for a search, for example "McDonalds" I get results in CHICAGO instead of San Francisco...

Any Idea what maybe happening? This is my query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=mcdonald&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&sensor=false&key=hereIsWhereMyKeyGoes
```

This is Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `radius` to search within.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=mcdonald&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=20&sensor=false&key=hereIsWhereMyKeyGoe
```

I used to have a similar problem with results from Chicago so that must be some sort of default area to search in.  To search near a location you must supply the `location` and `radius` parameters.

Comment: thanks dude, the documentation on this is really poor, they should add that both parameters are needed.